# Add references to project when control dropped from Visual Studio 2008 toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I drop a third-party control onto a visual design surface in Visual Studio, any library references required by the control are automatically added to my project. I have an inherited version of a third-party control that I've added to the toolbox. However, when I drag it onto a form, only some of the references to the underlying third-party libraries are added. How can I specify additional references to be added?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path to the DLL that contains the controls, read [this](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2007/02/13/ImportingReferencing+DLLs+In+Visual+Studio.aspx).

It's the same in VS2008 as in VS2005.

Comment: Well, my question in this case isn't how to add the reference, but rather how to code a control such that when it is dropped onto a design surface, necessary references are _automatically_ added to the project.

Comment: @David: The link you provided seems to be dead. Can you fix it?