# How to automatically reference BaseClass control when using toolbox for my Main Control - Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, user-controls, toolbox, assembly-references

First I want to thank upfront to anyone who will answer my question.

My problem is: 
I have created "base control" and from the base I have inherited my "main control". Now user will be adding my "main control" to the toolbox such that he (the user) can only drop it on the form on any project he wants, but I am getting error because the "base control" is not automatically referenced in the project where the "main control" is dropped. Only the "main control" automatically is referenced.

Just to mention that both controls are signed properly and will live in same directory when added in toolbox, but not in the GAC (It will really not work for me, unless there is no other solution).

I have found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262596/add-references-to-project-when-control-dropped-from-visual-studio-2008-toolbox) here but it is not answered and unfortunately I can't find answer anywhere at all.

Comment: This is about *assemblies*, not controls.  The designer has no way to find the assembly that contains the base class.  There is very little point in making the programmer's life difficult, just compile them into a single assembly.  Or use ILMerge.  Or use the GAC but then you also have to provide an installer so the programmer can get them deployed correctly for his own program.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thank you for your comment. At this moment that is how I do that - using GAC, but I was wondering if there is a way without using GAC. If I use GAC, client that will use my control will have difficulties when deploying his application. He will need to worry for properly deploying my controls as well..

Comment: I gave you **three** alternatives, choosing the one you like is up to you.